# ImageProperty in Neo4Django?

Tags: django, neo4j, neo4django

In regular Django models I typically use an ImageField to represent and store image attributes, for example:

```
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='folder')
```

I am using neo4django for a graph DB project and I notice that there is no 'ImageProperty' listed  here [https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/blob/master/neo4django/db/models/**init**.py](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/blob/master/neo4django/db/models/__init__.py).

How do people typical handle image fields when using neo4django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you store them in a blob storage like s3 or a filesystem and store only the references (e.g. URLs) in Neo4j.